# Debian Upgrade "Buster 10 to Bullseye 11" can no longer open or list mounted SFTP/SSH directories in VSCodium natively

Tags: debian, git, remote-access, vscode-extensions

In Debian Buster 10 with VSCodium, I could open folders of remote machines which were mounted in Debian's filesystem through nautilus - by accessing the "other locations" tab in the file explorer that opens when you open a new folder in VSCodium folder selection. Since upgrading I can no longer open or even list mounted filesystems in VSCodium. I have tried to use the "open remote - ssh" plugin but that attempts to install a script on the remote device which is not wanted or needed and for some of my remote environments is rejected. Is there any reason I have lost this capability or anything I can do to restore native access to remotely mounted file systems in VSCodium?

Before the upgrade I uninstalled Samba which left my native SSH/SFTP capabilities in Debian broken post upgrade, so I reinstalled nautilus and samba which restored native SSH/SFTP capabilities but now I can't read any mounted file systems in Debian from VSCodium folder selection. Even though I can see them mounted in nautilus. Where as in Buster I could work from any remote repository I had mounted in Debian.

I have also tried to use SSH FS extension for VSCodium, I can connect to my remote servers this way but it doesn't recognize when I am inside of a GIT repository and doesn't highlight saved changes - which is preventing me from adopting this approach.